# Div With Background Color Not Covering Child Div

Tags: html, css, height

I have two divs:

- `content2` which has my background color and has a `height:auto` and `width:100%`
- and another div inside `content2` called `extensive_look`

The latter is the container for my content and thus has a fixed width, is centered (with `margin:0 auto`), but has no background color. The idea is that content structures the content down to a certain width, and `content2` gives a background color that spans the width of the whole page.

The problem is that it seems `content2` does not cover all of the content with it's background color.

I first thought it might be because `extensive_look` has `position:relative; top:20px;` but even removing that didn't fix the problem.

The issue I'm talking about can be seen [here](http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html) if you scroll down to the bottom of the good examples section where you will see the background color ends early. How can I fix this issue? My code is below.

HTML:

```html
<div class="content2">
  <div id="extensive_look" style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative; top: 20px; height: auto;">
    <h1 align="center">Good Website Examples</h1> 
      <p>Check out these websites for some inspiration...</p>
      <div id="white_house" class="ext_image">
        <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="view_site"></div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id="abc" class="ext_image">
        <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="view_site"></div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id="quartz" class="ext_image">
        <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="view_site"></div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id="usatoday" class="ext_image">
        <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="view_site"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.content2 {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  min-height: 500px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to `#extensive_look`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to 'clear' the floated elements inside `#extensive_look`.

To do that you can either use:

```
#extensive_look { 
  overflow: hidden
}
```

Or you can create a clearfix class with the following styles and add that class to the extensive_look div.

`<div id="extensive_look" class="clearfix">`

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the extensive look at a website section (not to be confused with the extensive_look div which applies to the good examples section). I tried adding overflow:hidden to the div that controlls the width for that section, but it didn't work. It did work however for this section. How can I fix the other section?

Comment: That's caused by having `top: 20px` on the `.content` (styled inline).  If you want to move that from the top use `margin-top`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content2 {
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    min-height:500px;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

"Min-height" is your culprit, I believe. The computed height of the div is exactly 540px--which is the min-height plus 20px padding on top and bottom. Adding "overflow-y:auto" seems to fix the issue.